# how to find the same value if their length are not the same?

Tags: r, match

I would like to find which row of a value that has the same value of another one?
Here is the code:

```
> a
[1] 3 5 6
> num
     x  y z
1  112 55 0
2   23 21 1
3  121 56 2
4  132 15 3
5  123 15 4
6  132 45 5
7  132 41 6
8  179 45 7
```

To find out on which row of `num` has the same value that `a` has, is there a function I can use like `match` function? I tried this code (it would not work):

```
for(i in 1:length(num)){
  for (j in 1: length(a)){
    if (num$z[i]==a[j]){
      return(row(num[i]))
  }
 }
}
```

The outputs are the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code below. `lapply` returns a list and the list which_rows contains the rows in which a value of `a` appears in each column.

```
which_rows <- lapply(df1, function(x) which(x %in% a))
which_rows 
$x
integer(0)

$y
integer(0)

$z
[1] 4 6 7
```

Comment: what if I need to get the mode of it is numeric? I try `as.numeric(unlist(which_rows))` but the outputs are 1.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with the `match` function:

```
match(a, num$z)
# [1] 4 6 7
```

---

To get the full rows of `num` satisfying `z==a`:

```
num[match(a,num$z),]
#     x     y     z
#   132    15     3
#   132    45     5
#   132    41     6
```

or

```r
num %>% filter(z %in% a)
#     x     y     z
#   132    15     3
#   132    45     5
#   132    41     6
```

---

To get just the `y`:

```
num$y[match(a,num$z)]
# [1] 15 45 41
```

Comment: I would like to get num$y in which `a` and `num$z` have the same value.
I tried  `for(i in 1:length(match(binddf$juliandfdate, juliandivdate))) if(is.na(match(binddf$juliandfdate, juliandivdate)[i])==TRUE){return(row(match(binddf$juliandfdate, juliandivdate)[i]))}}`

Comment: See the edited answer